# How do we get the baseline of each fold in cross-validation?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

Given that I am using Scikit learn and cross-validation and want to compare my accuracy result for each fold with my baseline

I am using 10-fold cross-validation and how for each fold I return the baseline for that fold. is it possible?

```
clf= RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=20)
# 10-Fold Cross validation
scores = cross_val_score(clf, features, labels, cv=10)
scores
```

Result: array([0.45454545, 0.63636364, 0.8       , 0.8       , 0.6       ,
       0.6       , 0.5       , 0.9       , 0.66666667, 0.33333333])

Answer (score 1):

I think you look for: `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate`, see the docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate):

> **Returns:**
>   *scores : dict of float arrays of shape=(n_splits,)* 
>   Array of scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation. 
>   A dict of arrays containing the score/time arrays for each scorer is
>   returned. The possible keys for this dict are:
>
> **test_score** The score array for test scores on each cv split.
>
> **train_score** The score array for train scores on each cv split. 
>   [...]

---

**Minimal example:**

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

# Data
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]

# Model
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
cv_results = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=10)

# Print keys
print(sorted(cv_results.keys()))
# Print test_scores
print(cv_results['test_score'])
```

**Returns:**

```
['fit_time', 'score_time', 'test_score', 'train_score']
[ 0.34557351  0.34848715  0.26654262 -0.01126674  0.24875619  0.08731544
  0.13386583  0.14000888  0.2873109   0.00960079]
```

Comment: the test score is the accuracy result for each fold or the average of the label on each fold?

Comment: Read the docs: „The score array for test scores on each cv split“. Sounds to me like the score for each single step...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I don't know if this is correct:

```
X = np.array(features)
y = np.array(labels)
kf = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=20)
kf.get_n_splits(features)

print(kf)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    # print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    print(np.mean(y_test))
```

if a get the same randon_state, I expect to get the same folds.